# Fill a percentage width of table cell

Tags: html, css

How do I make an element take up a percentage width of a table cell? When I attempt to do a percentage, say 70%, it grows much larger than the containing cell. 70% should be smaller than the containing cell! Here's a barebones example of my page. The absolute positioning is necessary for some layering I want to do.

HTML

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <div>hello</div>
  </td>
  <td>
   <div>world</div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
td {
 position: relative;
 width: 10em;
}

div {
 position: absolute;
 width: 70%;
}
```

Comment: The absolute positioning is your problem.

Comment: I am doing a multi-layered bar graph, which requires the absolute positioning.

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using a third-party library for this? Ex. http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/columnchart.html

Comment: I'm not doing a traditional bar graph. It's 3D-ish and horizontal pointing. It's unique to my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matt Ball's comment got me on the right track. It's some extra markup.

HTML

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="bar">hello</div>
   </div>
  </td>
  <td>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="bar">world</div>
   </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
td {
 width: 10em;
}

.container {
 position: relative;
}

.bar {
 position: absolute;
 width: 70%;
}
```